# Issues retrieving user information for posts in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

So I'm having issues with retrieving information using Laravel's eager loading.  I.m trying to call all Post objects with their respectful users added to the query.

Here is what I have:

The query is

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::with('user')->get();



    return view('posts.index', compact('posts', $posts));
}
```

In my User and Post models I have each defined with, what I believe are the appropriate relationships,  Here they are exactly:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
}
```

And the Post is:

```
<?php

 namespace App;

use App\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
```

{

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title', 'content', 'followers',
];

public function user() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
}
```

The error I get is just the post being return with no information about the user, such as their name, which I want to use in a loop for the Posts Index page when displaying all post.

Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: How are post and user even connected?

Answer (score 1):

you can get user data in blade view directly,
it will automatically run the query itself

post/index.blade.php

```
$post->user->attributes
```

when calling that method, it equivalent with

```
select * from user where user.id = post.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.  I was doing it right, but when trying to print the user's name I use the following code $post->name instead of $post->user->name.  sorry about that.